# How to find the most common int in a 2d array of ints?

Tags: c#, paint.net

OK, so I'm just starting to think how to implement a new graphical plugin for Paint.NET and I will need to know how to find the most common integer in a 2d array of integers.  Is there a built-in to C# way to do this?  Or, does anyone have a slick way to do it?

The array will look something like this:

```
300 300 300 300 300 300 300
  0 150 300 300 300 300 300
  0   0 150 300 300 300 300
  0   0   0   0 300 300 300
  0   0   0   0 150 300 300
  0   0   0   0   0 150 300
  0   0   0   0   0   0 300
```

I would need to know that 300 is the most common number in the array.  If there is no "most common" then just return the center number (the array dimintions will always be odd x odd) 0.

I'll be implementing this using a "brute force" algorithm unless you experts can come up with something faster.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: More info...

The values will almost always be VERY diverse (more diverse than my example array).  The values will be in the range of 0-360.  The size of the array will be 5x5 to about 17x17 depending on speed of the algorithm.  The result will be calculate once for each pixel in a large image... so faster is better. ;)

Comment: Sounds like a fun problem - I bet there's an answer.  Color me interested.

Comment: What do you do if it's a tie (for example 300 and 125 both have the same hit count)?

Comment: @Michael, it was stated in the original problem: "If there is no "most common" then just return the center number" which means that none of the solutions posted so far meet the requirements.

Comment: Can you sample a set of random pixels and use the mode of the sample? I guess not, but you may have some statistic that helps.

Comment: Are you implementing median filtering in HSL?

Comment: @artificialidiot: something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the LocalHistogramEffect code in Paint.NET, notably LocalHistorgramEffect.RenderRect.

I walks the input image, maintaining a histogram of intensities for each source pixel withing 'r' pixels of the destination pixel. As the output pixels are traversed, it adds the leading edge to the histogram and subtracts the trailing edge. It handles all the edge cases well, and is quite fast. It's the basis for the Median, Unfocus, Outline, and Remove Noise effects.

Adapting this to support Hue instead of RGB intensity would be rather trivial.

The performance is quite good, and for your purposes it operates in O(r^2+w*r+n*w), where r is the radius, w is the width of the image, and n is the number of levels in the histogram.

-tjackson

Answer (score 6):

It's at least O(n*m) any way you slice it -- you are going to have to look at each cell at least once. The place to economize is in where you accumulate the counts of each value before looking for the most common; if your integers vary over a relatively small range (they are uint16, let's say), then you might be able to simply use a flat array instead of a map.

I guess you could also keep a running count *x*,*y* of the current top and second-closest candidate for "most common" and early-out as soon as you've less than (n*m)-(x-y) cells left to look at, since at that point there's no way the runner-up could outpace the top candidate.

Integer ops like this are pretty fast; even for a megapixel image the brute force algorithm should only take a couple milliseconds.

I notice you've edited your original question to say that the pixels value from 0..255 -- in that case, definitely go with a simple flat array; that's small enough to easily fit into the l1 dcache and a lookup in a flat array is trez quick.

**[edit] :** Dealing with the "no most common number" case is very simple once you've built the histogram array: all have you to do is walk through it to find the "most" and "second most" common numbers; if they're equally frequent, then by definition there is no one most common.

```
const int numLevels = 360; // you said each cell contains a number [0..360)
int levelFrequencyCounts[numLevels]; // assume this has been populated such that levelFrequencyCounts[i] = number of cells containing "i"
int mostCommon = 0, runnerUp = 0;
for (int i = 1 ; i < numLevels ; ++i)
{
  if ( levelFrequencyCounts[i] > levelFrequencyCounts[mostCommon] )
  {
    runnnerUp = mostCommon;
    mostCommon = i;
  }
}

if ( levelFrequencyCounts[mostCommon] != levelFrequencyCounts[runnerUp] )
{
   return mostCommon;
}
else
{
   return CenterOfInputData; // (something like InputData[n/2][m/2])
}
```

Comment: You will be able to determine your outcome IF the count of any key becomes greater than 1/2 the available cells. On small areas it won't matter much though.

Comment: Still small enough to easily fit in an array!

Answer (score 3):

> how would I do something like this in C#?

Something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> d = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (int value in matrix)
{
 if (!d.ContainsKey(value))
  d.Add(value, 1);
 else
  d[value] = d[value] + 1;
}
KeyValuePair<int, int> biggest = null;
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> found in d)
{
  if ((biggest == null) || (biggest.Value < found.Value))
    biggest = found;
}
```

Comment: Given that the values are constrained to 0..360, an array like `int numOccurances[360]` could be simpler and cheaper than a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

One option is LINQ - a bit inefficient, but OK for non-huge arrays:

```
    var max = (from cell in data.Cast<int>()
               group cell by cell into grp
               select new { Key = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() } into agg
               orderby agg.Count descending
               select agg).First();
    Console.WriteLine(max.Key + ": " + max.Count);
```

Or with a jagged array:

```
    var max = (from row in data
              from cell in row
              group cell by cell into grp
              select new {Key = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()} into agg
              orderby agg.Count descending
              select agg).First();
    Console.WriteLine(max.Key + ": " + max.Count);
```

In reality, I would probably use a dictionary/count. This example without LINQ, just "because":

```
    Dictionary<int, int> counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach (int value in data)
    {
        int count;
        counts.TryGetValue(value, out count);
        counts[value] = count + 1;
    }
    int maxCount = -1, maxValue = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in counts)
    {
        if (pair.Value > maxCount)
        {
            maxCount = pair.Value;
            maxValue = pair.Key;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(maxCount + ": " + maxValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

If speed is your primary concern, do not use a dictionary. Stick with an array of bytes. Try this:

```
// stores hit counts (0-360)
short[] hitCounts = new short[361];

// iterate through 2d array and increment hit counts
for (int i = 0; i < toEvaluate.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < toEvaluate[i].Length; j++)
        hitCounts[toEvaluate[i][j]]++;
}

int greatestHitCount = 0; // the hit count of the current greatest value
int greatest = -1; // the current greatest valeu

// iterate through values (0-360) and evalute hit counts
for (int i = 0; i < hitCounts.Length; i++)
{
    // the hit count of hitCounts[i] is higher than the current greatest hit count value
    if (hitCounts[i] > greatestHitCount)
    {
        greatestHitCount = vals[i]; // store the new hit count
        greatest = i; // store the greatest value
    }
    // there is already a value with the same hit count (which is the greatest)
    else if (hitCounts[i] == greatestHitCount)
        greatest = -1; // there are more than one value, we can't use this if it ends up being the greatest
}

if (greatest >= 0) // no greatest value found
    return greatest;

// figure out the middle x and y value
int x = (toEvaluate.Length - 1) / 2 + 1;
int y = (toEvaluate[x].Length - 1) / 2 + 1;

// return the value at the center of the 2d array as the value
return toEvaluate[x][y];
```

When speed becomes a concern over readability, you end up with necessarily ugly code.  The above could definitely benefit from refactoring (hence overdoing the comments), but it should run fast. If it isn't fast enough, you can gain even more optimizations by moving it to unmanaged code.

Comment: Hey - this is nearly identical to what I was about to post!

Comment: Just a couple nitpicks - since the incoming matrix can be up to 17x17, the vals[] array type needs to be larger than a byte to avoid possible overflow. Also assuming that 360 is a valid data value, the array should be sized to 361 (obviously, the array size should be a constant defined somewhere).

Comment: vals[] represents the hit counts (for your values 0-360), not the actual values. 17*17 is 289. The max value of a byte (which is unsigned by default) is 512. You're right about the 360 thing.  Will fix.

Comment: Hmm - my bytes can only hold 255.  I guess I need to upgrade. :)

Comment: That makes me wrong twice!  Yar.  I guess eventually 2^8 starts looking like 2^9 to my addled brain.  Changing to short.

Answer (score 1):

Your image:

```
300+ 300+ 300+ 300 300 300 300
  0+ 150+ 300+ 300 300 300 300
  0+   0+ 150+ 300 300 300 300
  0    0    0    0 300 300 300
  0    0    0    0 150 300 300
  0    0    0    0   0 150 300
  0    0    0    0   0   0 300
```

Marked (+) numbers are your window. w,h is your window dimensions. Apply [bucket sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) (as other people suggested since your value ranges are quite limited). Don't cut your evaluation halfway as [Crashworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492923/how-to-find-the-most-common-int-in-a-2d-array-of-ints/492960#492960) suggests. Don't throw your result yet. This is the first step.

```
300- 300- 300- 300 300 300 300
  0. 150. 300. 300 300 300 300
  0.   0. 150. 300 300 300 300
  0+   0+   0+   0 300 300 300
  0    0    0    0 150 300 300
  0    0    0    0   0 150 300
  0    0    0    0   0   0 300
```

Shift your window. Instead of adding, subtract the buckets in the last row/column you passed and add the new buckets. This way you examine each pixel 2(w+h) times i.e. when it crosses the window boundary, instead of w*h times, i.e. while that pixel is in the window, in a naive implementation.

In other words, You need to move your window like this:

```
|  ^->|  ^
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
V->|  V->|
```

I assume you are trying to implement a nonlinear convolution filter.

Corrections welcome.

Comment: I will be processing many pixels in a row, so I had already thought of the optimization of removing the left column of data from the array before adding the new right most column.  I have done similar shortcuts in previous Paint.NET plugins.

Comment: Yeah, exploiting the data locality like that is a good call. I wrote my answer before Bolt made his edit about sliding a convo filter over an image -- at the time, I thought he wanted to find the mode value over the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Michael beat me to the post, but I'd do likewise, something like this:

```
        int MaxValueIn2dArray(int[,] matrix)
    {
        var d = new int[360];
        int MaxValue = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x <= matrix.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= matrix.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
            {
                d[matrix[x, y]]++;
            }
        }
        foreach (int value in d)
        {
            if (value > MaxValue) MaxValue = value;
        }
        return MaxValue;
    }
```

It would need to be optimized for your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

All I'll offer is for any algorithm that checks every cell (which is pretty much what you'd expect to do) do two extra things:

1.) Make sure the routine exits when the count for the currently most common value > (M x N / 2). If something has >50% coverage on your grid then it's the most common value, no need to continue. If your routine only needs to be right MOST of the time then you could lower the percentage and treat it as a heuristic. You could even run some analysis that spits out something like if coverage is >37.6% then 99.9% of the time it'll be the most common value and then use that percentage.

2.) If there is any way you can determine in which side, corner or general location (outer edges, middle, etc.) the most common values are likely to be, you could then scan in that order which together with optimization 1 above could shave off a lot of your scanning. For instance in your example the top right is heavy on the common value. If this was determinable by some heuristic you could scan from the top right to the bottom left in some fashion. If the pattern of scanning needed is complex, pre-generate it.